# Create lookup column in document library to attachment in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, document-library, attachments

I currently have a workflow that creates a document from a list. This works well. I am currently looking for a way to take an attachment from the list and somehow append it to the document. I understand that you can not attach things to a document library. That's why I want to create a look up column to the attachment.

E.g. I have ListA with ListitemA with attachment. Using a workflow, I created a document from ListitemA in DocumentLibraryA. In I want documentA to have a field that looks up the attachment from ListitemA. Perhaps a link.

Anyways, I was wondering if anyone could point me to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
Create a hyperlink field in document library. When a document is created in the library, update the hyperlink column with the url that points to the list item display form that has the attachments. The url format could be `http://site/lists/ListA/dispform.aspx?ID=ListItemA_ID`. Or a direct url to the attachment is also possible using this format `http://site/Lists/ListA/Attachments/ListItemA_ID/fileattachment.docx`

**Solution 2** Create a folder in a document library first, create the document in that folder and finally copy the list item attachments in that folder.

**Solution 3** Use Document Sets content type in a document library. Each document set can have multiple documents. This might be complex using workflows.